# \sum_{k=0, k even}^n {n \choose k}*2^k = \frac{(3^n)+((-1)^n)}{2}

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Prove the following combinatoric identity:

$$\sum_{k=0, k even}^n {n \choose k}*2^k = \frac{(3^n)+((-1)^n)}{2}$$

Comment: How have you tried?

Comment: Replace the $2^k$ by $x^k$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE ! When you ask a question, it is best to include more context; tell us a bit more why you want to know the answer, what you have tried or what you think could be useful to solve the problem... See also this page of the FAQ : https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\left(1+2\right)^{n}+\left(1-2\right)^{n}=\sum_{k}\binom{n}{k}2^{^{k}}+\sum_{k}\binom{n}{k}\left(-2\right){}^{k}$

Which terms fall away against eachother?